# RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED doesn't work on Huawei devices API 28 and above

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to run a service when the device restarts. But I couldn't achieve this on API 28 and above. The code below works fine under API 28 and below, but is not responsive at all in higher versions. I haven't looked through many answers, but I couldn't come to a conclusion. I would be glad if you help.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


    <application
         //...
     <service
        android:name=".Services.NotificationService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name = "app.tutorialspoint.com.notifyme.NotificationService" />
            <category android:name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

         <receiver
            android:name=".Receivers.DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <!--For HTC devices-->
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

> My Receiver

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   Intent intentService = new Intent(context,NotificationService.class);
    intentService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(intentService);
    } else {
        context.startService(intentService);
    }

        //i added it for testing bot doesnt work
        /*if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
             //do something...
        }*/
   }
}
```

> EDIT
>
> The code also works on api 28 and above. I tested it on different
> devices and found it working. Doesn't work on Huawei devices only!

Comment: I would not expect a `Toast` from the background to work on modern versions of Android. Try logging with Logcat. Also, your question mentions wanting to run a service, but your code does not show that, so we cannot point out any problems with that code.

Comment: I added this as a test. Logcat, service or nothing else will not work. I am updating the code.